# How can I plot a loxodrome?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, geometry

Can someone show me how to plot a rhumb line (loxodrome) in *Mathematica* via the `ParametricPlot3D` function?

Here is what I got so far:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[λ]/Cosh[Cot[π/4] λ], Sin[λ]/Cosh[Cot[π/4] λ], Tanh[Cot[π/4] λ]},
                 {λ, 0, π}]
```

I am trying to get this one:

[image: loxodrome]

Comment: I edited the question with something that shows my tries. I want to draw a rhumb line that starts from the norh pole and has a compas direction of 45°

Comment: You can look at the source code of [this demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/Loxodrome/). I think that covers it.

Comment: Thanks Jens, I saw that allready, but was unable to exctract the loxodrome equasion from it.

Comment: Very confused...I thought a loxodrome was one of those arenas from antiquity where they used to race salmon.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a version where you can manipulate the angle under which the meridians of longitude are crossed, using the `k` slider. To get the full loxodrome from pole to pole, you have to plot from $-2\pi/k$ to $2\pi/k$, which is done automatically here when `a = 1`.

Furthermore, you can influence which meridian is crossed by changing $\lambda_0$. This is the same as rotating the loxodrome.

[image: Manipulate object for loxodromes]

```
Manipulate[Show[
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[.4], Specularity[White, 30], Orange, 
    Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .95]}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[λ]/Cosh[k (λ - λ0)], Sin[λ]/Cosh[k (λ - λ0)], Tanh[k (λ - λ0)]},
    {λ, -2 a π/k, 2 a π/k},
    MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[3, 7], PlotPoints -> ControlActive[20, 50]
    ] /. l : Line[pts_] :> ControlActive[l, Tube[pts]], 
  SphericalRegion -> True
  ],
 {k, -1, 1, .09},
 {{a, 1}, .01, 1},
 {λ0, 0, 2 π}
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I needed. Could you also explain me why `k` needs to be in range from -0,5 to -0,005 and what does it stand for?

Comment: @Ivana Sorry, I wasn't consistent in my notation with the English wiki. `k` is defined as `k=Cot[beta]` where `beta` is the crossing angle. `k`'s *meaningful* interval is maybe [-1,1] although it cannot be 0 (which is 90 degree) and close to 0 there are too many lines and the graphic gets slow. But you could of course use something like `{k, -1, 1, .09}` (cleverly overjumping the 0).

Comment: You could use `Sech[]`... ;)

Comment: This hangs *Mathematica* 7.  Before I dig into it: any idea why that would happen?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My first guess is the replacement of `Line` with `Tube`. `Tube` was new in 7 and may not work as expected. You could remove the `/.l:Line...` part to test this. Then you could decrease the `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints` settings and if nothing helps even remove `Opacity` and `Specularity`.

Answer (score 10):

For a better presentation of the curve we would like to see also the background - in this case a sphere.
Let's use your definition of the curve with appropriate options, e.g.  `MeshFunctions -> {#3&}` to visualize parallels.

```
Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[ {Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, 
                    {u, -Pi, Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotPoints -> 80, 
                    PlotStyle -> { Lighter @ Blue, Specularity[Green, 10]}, Axes -> None,
                    Boxed -> False, Mesh -> 25, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{ Cos[ω]/Cosh[Cot[Pi/4]*ω], Sin[ω]/Cosh[Cot[Pi/4]*ω], 
                     Tanh[Cot[Pi/4]*ω]}, {ω, 0, Pi}, 
                     PlotStyle -> {White, Thick}]]
```

[image]

Now it should be much easier to get any desired specific effects.

For more customized presentation we define a function drawing the loxodrome:

```
loxodrome[a_, b_, ω0_] /; 0.1 < a < Pi/2 && -1 < b < -0.01 && 0 < ω0 < 2 Pi :=
  Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[
        {Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, {u, -Pi, Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}, 
         MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotPoints -> 80, 
         PlotStyle -> {Lighter@Blue, Specularity[Green, 10], Opacity[3/5]},
         Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> {12, 12}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #4 &}, 
         MeshStyle -> {Dashed, Dashed}], 
    ParametricPlot3D[
        { Cos[ω]/Cosh[Cot[a](ω - ω0)], Sin[ω]/Cosh[Cot[a](ω - ω0)], Tanh[Cot[a](ω- ω0)]}, 
        {ω, -2 Pi/b, 2 Pi/b}, PlotStyle -> {White, Thick} ]
     ]
```

Now we can manipulate the parameters, `a`, `b` and `ω0`, e.g. `a` determines inclination of the curve to parallels:

```
Manipulate[ loxodrome[a, b, ω0], 
            {{a, 3Pi/8}, 0.1, Pi/2}, {{ω0, Pi}, 0, 2 Pi}, {{b, -1/2}, -1, -0.01}]
```

or simply specify the arguments:

```
loxodrome[15 Pi/32, -1/8, 19 Pi/10]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Artes, appreciate your help. I am trying to get this one http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Loxodrome-2.gif but unsuccesfully

Comment: @Ivana I provided in my answer meridians and parallels as you expected. Does this satisfy your needs ?

Answer (score 8):

Using the formulae from [here](http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes3d/loxodromie/loxodromie.shtml), here is a way to plot the loxodrome of a general surface of revolution, specialized to the spherical case:

```
With[{α = π/4}, (* angle from the latitude *)
     f[u_] := Cos[u]; g[u_] := Sin[u];
     lox = DSolveValue[{l'[u] == Cot[α] (Sqrt[#.#] &[{f'[u], g'[u]}])/f[u], l[0] == -π/2},
                       l, u];
     Show[RevolutionPlot3D[{f[u], g[u]}, {u, -π, π}, 
                           MeshStyle -> Directive[Thin, GrayLevel[1/4], Opacity[1/2]]], 
          ParametricPlot3D[{f[u] Cos[lox[u]], f[u] Sin[lox[u]], g[u]}, {u, -π, π}] /.
          Line -> Tube]]
```

[image: spherical loxodrome]

One can do something similar for the [pseudosphere](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pseudosphere.html):

```
With[{α = π/12},
     f[u_] := Sech[u]; g[u_] := u - Tanh[u];
     lox = DSolveValue[{l'[u] == Cot[α] (Sqrt[#.#] &[{f'[u], g'[u]}])/f[u], l[0] == -π/2},
                       l, u];
     Show[RevolutionPlot3D[{f[u], g[u]}, {u, -3, 3}, 
                           MeshStyle -> Directive[Thin, GrayLevel[1/4], Opacity[1/2]]], 
          ParametricPlot3D[{f[u] Cos[lox[u]], f[u] Sin[lox[u]], g[u]}, {u, -3, 3}] /.
          Line -> Tube]]
```

[image: pseudospherical loxodrome]

(Of course, one can use `NDSolveValue[]` instead if the DE for the loxodrome does not have a closed form solution.)

Comment: Wonderful extension!

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, loxodrome is the image under the stereographic projection transformation of a logarithmic spiral. So I use the following approach.

Suppose the sphere is `Sphere[{0,0,1},1]`, and the stereographic projection is

```
stereoMap[{x_, y_}] = 
  Block[{t}, 
    t {0, 0, 2} + (1 - t) {x, y, 0} /. 
      Solve[EuclideanDistance[
          t {0, 0, 2} + (1 - t) {x, y, 0}, {0, 0, 1}] == 1 && t != 1, 
       t,Reals] // Simplify][[1]];
```

That is

$$\{x,y\}\mapsto \left\{\frac{4 x}{x^2+y^2+4},\frac{4 y}{x^2+y^2+4},\frac{2 \left(x^2+y^2\right)}{x^2+y^2+4}\right\}$$

- At first we draw a log spiral curve in the plane.

```
angle0 = 50;
angle = 30;
logspiralMap[θ_] := 
  With[{a = .05, b = .15}, 
   a*E^(b*θ)  {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}];
logspiral2d = 
 ParametricPlot[logspiralMap[θ], {θ, 0, angle0}, 
  PlotStyle -> Green, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

- Then we mapping the `logspiral3d` to the unit sphere by `stereoMap`.

```
loxodromeMap = stereoMap@*logspiralMap;
pt = logspiralMap[angle];
qt = loxodromeMap[angle];
line = Graphics3D[{Red, Line[{{0, 0, 2}, PadRight[pt, 3]}], 
    PointSize[Large], Point[qt], Point[PadRight[pt, 3]]}];
logspiral3d = 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   PadRight[logspiralMap[θ], 3], {θ, 0, angle}, 
   PlotStyle -> Green];
loxodrom = 
  ParametricPlot3D[loxodromeMap[θ], {θ, 0, angle0}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue];
Show[logspiral3d, loxodrom, line, 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], Sphere[{0, 0, 1}, 1]}], 
 ViewPoint -> {2.88, 0.33, 1.73}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
loxodromes[a_, b_] :=
 {2 a E^(b u) Cos[u],
  2 a E^(b u) Sin[u],
  a^2 E^(2 b u) - 1} / (1 + a^2 E^(2 b u))

Show[

 ParametricPlot3D[
  loxodromes[1, 0.1],
  {u, -16 Pi, 16 Pi},
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]],

 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], Sphere[]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: `{u, -16 Pi, 16 Pi}`  get  a good result.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it